# python replace ".* " with ".\n*" except for ". " and ".\n"

Tags: python, regex

I have a text in a file with some lines like

```
blabla.blabla
```

And I want have this result:

```
blabla.
blabla
```

ignoring the cases in which there is already the result that I want or

```
blabla. blabla
```

Please help me. I think that I have to exploit `re.sub` function but I can't figure out how to handle it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you want to insert a new line after every '`.`' unless it's already followed by a new line or a space?

Comment: What if there are two dots, like `bla..blabla`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a dot not followed by a whitespace character (including newlines):

```
(\.)(?!\s)
```

Replace it with `\1\n`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qiLe2B/1

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a file `text.txt` with the following contents:

```
blabla.blabla
blabla. blabla
one.two
three. four. five
```

To get the needed result we use `re.sub()` function with specific regex pattern:

```
import re

with open('test.txt', 'r') as fh:
    result = re.sub(r'(\w+\.)(?=\S)', r'\1\n', fh.read())

print(result)
```

The output:

```
blabla.
blabla
blabla. blabla
one.
two
three. four. five
```